# Returning the factorial of 10 using recursion in java

Tags: java

Hello I have written the following code to return the factorial of n when the the value is 10 but i cant get my program to work. I have never used Java before and I am a beginner.

```
public static int Factorial(n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return( n * Factorial(n-1) );
    }
}

public static int main(args) {
    System.out.println(Factorial(10));
}
```

Comment: This is a poorly written question. Please elaborate on *i cant get my program to work*. Does it compile? Error messages? Compiles but doesn't run as expected? What?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `public static int Factorial(n)` is not a valid method declaration. `n` is of type int, so specify that in the list of parameters: `public static int Factorial(int n) {`. The same goes for your `main` method, it must take a `String[] array` as parameters.

Comment: The `main` method must have the signature `public static void main(String[] args)` but yours does not. Java won't know where to begin execution if that method signature is not found.

Comment: After compiling my program i get this following message, TestFact.java:2: class, interface, or enum expected
public int Factorial(n)
       ^
TestFact.java:6: class, interface, or enum expected
    } else{
    ^
TestFact.java:8: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
TestFact.java:10: class, interface, or enum expected
  public static int main(args) {
                ^
TestFact.java:12: class, interface, or enum expected
  }
  ^
5 errors

Comment: Please look at a Java tutorial online to learn some of the basics. And don't put code or messages in comments. Please edit your question with the correct information. There's an edit link there you should use.

Comment: I suggest you creating a Hello World application first.  You're missing essential pieces of valid syntax which wouldn't even allow it to compile in the first place.

Comment: Thanks I will go look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack a few type definitions and the required main method. Your class should look like this to work:

```
public class Main {
    public static int Factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return(n * Factorial(n-1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Factorial(10));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
int factorial(int n) 
{
 return (n>=1 ? n * factorial(n-1) : 1);
}
```